# Copy data from one MySQL table to another when data intersect using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array-intersect

I'm new to programming and would really appreciate your help. :) So, I have a `USER` table and a `SALES` table. On the `SALES` table I only have name and last name of the users. On the `USER` table I have `name`, `last name`, `USER_ID`, `email` and etc...

I need to copy the `USER_ID` from the `USER` table to the `SALES` table when `NAME` and `LAST NAME` are a match.

Here is the structure:

```
USER_TABLE_A
USER_ID_A
NAME_LASTNAME_A

SALES_TABLE_B
ROW_ID_B
NAME_B
LASTNAME_B
USER_ID_B (empty)
```

So far I got both tables to show data when they intersect but have no idea where to go from here. Could anyone please help?

```
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT name_B, lastname_B, user_id_B, row_id_B FROM sales_table_B WHERE name_B IS NOT NULL AND lastname_B IS NOT NULL", $db);
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT name_lastname_A, user_id_A FROM user_table_A WHERE name_lastname_A IS NOT NULL", $db);
    $a1 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    $id = $row['row_id_B'];
    $name1.$id = $row['name_B']." ".$row['lastname_B'];
    array_push($a1, $name1.$id);
}
    $a2 = array();
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {
    $id2 = $row2['user_id_A'];
    $name2.$id2 = $row2['name_lastname_A'];
    array_push($a2, $name2.$id2);
} 
    $result = array_intersect($a1,$a2);
    print_r($result);
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: In order to copy you're going to have to use an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: you can do merging of tables in a SELECT statement using JOIN. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much Darshan!! Your answer was missing a ) after limit 1 but with the adjustment it worked beautifully! Here is the code that worked:

```
UPDATE sales_table_b
SET user_id_b = (SELECT user_table_a.user_id_a
                 FROM user_table_a
                 WHERE user_table_a.name_lastname_a = CONCAT(sales_table_b.name_b, ' ' , sales_table_b.lastname_b) LIMIT 1)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
          FROM user_table_a
          WHERE user_table_a.name_lastname_a = CONCAT(sales_table_b.name_b, ' ' , sales_table_b.lastname_b))
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that `NAME_LASTNAME_A` column in `USER_TABLE_A` is a concatenation of `NAME_B` and `LASTNAME_B` columns of `SALES_TABLE_B`, following `UPDATE` query should update the ids:

```
update sales_table_b
set b.user_id_b = (
 select user_id_a from user_table_a
 where name_lastname_a = concat(b.name_b, ' ' , b.lastname_b)
 limit 1
 where exists(
  select user_id_a from user_table_a
  where name_lastname_a = concat(b.name_b, ' ' , b.lastname_b)
 )
)
```

Please note that in case of multiple users having same first and last name, id of the first matching user will be considered.

Comment: Thank you so much Darshan!! Your answer was missing a ) after limit 1 but with the adjustment it worked beautifully!